# Upload de arquivos (sempre em pastas diferentes)

Tags: php, upload

Gostaria de saber se é possível (e como eu poderia fazer) eu criar um sistema de upload onde sempre que eu subir um arquivo, ele vá para uma pasta diferente (sempre), e me mostre (ou grave) o caminho que ele gerou. É possível fazer isso?

**Motivo**: Sempre gero propostas em PDF que ficam com 10MB, então gostaria de ao invés de enviar para o cliente anexo, envio o link para ele fazer download da proposta. Contudo, um cliente não pode ver a proposta do outro, por isso gostaria de sempre fazer o upload para uma pasta diferente.

O código que tenho de base é esse:

```
    <?php
    $pasta = "/pasta/onde/o/arquivo/sera/salvo";
    $dest = $pasta."/".$file_name; 
    if(!move_uploaded_file($file, $dest)) { 
    echo "Não foi possível enviar o arquivo!"; 
    } else {
       echo "Arquivo enviado com sucesso!";
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: Você usa alguma biblioteca para gerar o pdf? Geralmente, é preciso especificar onde o arquivo será salvo, assim sendo bastaria criar um padrão para nomenclatura, mas pode variar de biblioteca pra biblioteca.

Comment: Provavelmente esse não é o método mais seguro de controlar o acesso aos arquivos, visto que , mesmo que você use nomes não padronizados , é possível que eventualmente eles sejam expostos...

Answer (score 5):

Aqui fica uma ideia de como poderias fazer:

```
<?php

   // Pasta de upload
   $updir =  "/upload/";


   // criar pasta random .../upload/RANDOM/
   $finaldir = $updir . md5(openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(23)) . "/";


  if (!is_dir($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . $finaldir)) {
     mkdir($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . $finaldir);         
  }

  // nome ficheiro
  $file = $finaldir . $_FILES["file"]["name"];

 // salvar ficheiro upload para a pasta
 copy($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . $file);

 //Salvar em base dados
 $sql = "INSERT INTO tabela (ficheiro, user) VALUES ('".$file."', 'xpto')";
 mysql_query($sql);

 ?>
```

Comment: O metodo `mt_rand` nao garante unicidade, o que parece ser um requisito do OP.

Comment: ok uniqid() tambem dá ------ Ja Agora: The output generated by the sprintf() and mt_rand() calls is identical to com_create_guid() results.

Comment: Nota: ao user `uniqid`, devera' usar a flag `$more_entropy = true`. Se a flag for `false`, o valor retornado sera o tempo actual em microsegundos - ou seja, nao garante unicidade.

Comment: Pronto melhor ainda: openssl_random_pseudo_bytes()

Answer (score 1):

Para garantir um nome uniquo, basta usar um *guid* (globally unique identifier) para gerar o nome da pasta, e depois guardar la' o ficheiro.

```
string com_create_guid ( void )
```

Fonte: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.com-create-guid.php

Answer (score 1):

Pra sua necessidade eu faria o seguinte:

Criaria as pastas no padrão:

- ano
- mes
- dia
- hora minuto segundo (tudo junto)
- nome do cliente (slug => sem caracteres especiais e minusculo)

Então ficaria assim:

```
    /2014/01/31/092631/fulano-de-tal/arquivo.pdf
```

Acho mais organizado do que criar um hash do tipo:

```
    /19090d9f0e92wd0920e90d9f029d09/arquivo.pdf
```

Answer (score 0):

Tenho uma aplicação em PHP que faz o upload de ficheiros gerados automaticamente por postos clientes e, para que se faça um download seguro, criei um "token" único  à semelhança do que já foi dito e depois tenho uma tabela que gere os downloads. Esta tabela guarda o token do ficheiro, cria um link para download (tenho todos os ficheiros na mesma pasta referenciados na bd) e tem uma data/hora associada ao download que estabelece um tempo limite para o fazer (no meu caso de 2 dias).
Uma estrutura de pastas por cliente só faz sentido se os ficheiros tiverem de ser acedidos de outra forma (FTP por exemplo), senão basta ter um registo com o nome do ficheiro na base de dados.

Answer (score 0):

> Motivo: Sempre gero propostas em PDF que ficam com 10MB, então gostaria de ao invés de enviar para o cliente anexo, envio o link para ele fazer download da proposta. Contudo, um cliente não pode ver a proposta do outro, por isso gostaria de sempre fazer o upload para uma pasta diferente.

Nesse caso, o que você precisa é das duas uma:

1. Implementar um controle de acesso, exigindo por exemplo que o cliente entre com uma senha antes de baixar o arquivo;
2. Usar um token aleatório e difícil de adivinhar (*unguessable*), ou alternativamente o hash do [conteúdo do] próprio arquivo

O caso 1 a primeira vista parece inconveniente para o usuário - e é mesmo - mas passa uma boa impressão: é mais fácil convencer um cliente [leigo em questões de segurança] que seu arquivo está "protegido" por meio de uma senha do que explicando para ele que a "chance de alguém sem o link adivinhar o token é muito próxima de zero" (e você **vai** ouvir a pergunta: "mas e se alguém descobrir?").

No segundo caso, você pode usar um valor aleatório - talvez um GUID/UUID - como as outras respostas sugeriram, mas também pode fazer um hash (ex.: SHA-256) do conteúdo do arquivo. A vantagem nesse segundo caso é que, se o mesmo arquivo for carregado duas vezes no servidor, somente uma única cópia do mesmo precisa ser armazenada. Sim, eu sei que "um cliente não pode ver a proposta do outro", mas se as duas forem iguais, que diferença faz? (i.e. não há nenhuma informação que mostre que outro cliente também tem acesso ao mesmo arquivo)

Answer (score 0):

Acho bem útil mudar as pastas, mas acredito que você poderia fazer esse procedimento de uma maneira mais dinâmica.

Poderia gerar o PDF já direto no PHP e setar a *header* do mesmo, existem classes como o MPDF que facilitam esse procedimento. Segue um [link de um tutorial](http://www.voltsdigital.com.br/labs/gerando-arquivo-pdf-a-partir-de-um-html-com-o-php/).

Assim, você poderia economizar espaço em seu servidor.