# como pego imagem vindo de um input file?

Tags: php, html, arquivo, imagem, input

Alguem me diz, o que eu preciso pra pegar uma imagem do input file e mostrá-la ou salvá-la? preciso usar javascript? ou só o html e php?

Já pesquisei no google, mas n estou achando algo explicando passo a passo, ja procurei aqui tbm, mas só vi coisas um pouco mais especificas...

Comment: Pesquise por upload de arquivos em PHP, talvez te ajude.

Comment: Utilizando o $_FILES - http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php

Comment: Existem também várias respostas referentes - http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/3404/upload-de-arquivos-sempre-em-pastas-diferentes

Answer (score 3):

**Pre visualização antes do upload**

Para mostrar uma pré visualização da imagem antes de realizar o upload, veja abaixo um exemplo:

```js
function ImagePreview(input)
{

    if (input.files && input.files[0])
 {

        var r = new FileReader();

        r.onload = function(e)
  {
   $("#img_preview").show();
            $("#img_preview").attr("src", e.target.result);
        }

        r.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);

    }
}

$().ready(function() {

 hide_empty_image = false;
 set_blank_to_empty_image = false;
 set_image_border = true;

 if (hide_empty_image)
  $("#img_preview").hide();

 if (set_blank_to_empty_image)
  $("#img_preview").attr("src","data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAAD/ACwAAAAAAQABAAACADs=");

 if (set_image_border)
  $("#img_preview").css("border", "1px solid #05bbcc");
  
    $("#img_preview").css("width", "150px");
    $("#img_preview").css("height", "150px");

 $("#img_input").change(function(){
  ImagePreview(this);
 });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form id="frm1">
    <input type="file" id="img_input" />
    <br /><img id="img_preview" src="" alt="Image Preview" />
</form>
```

**Para fazer o upload**

Há centenas de casos no StackOverflow, você pode consultar essa resposta: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/93198/4793

Caso queira encontrar mais resultados: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/search?q=php+upload